# Node.JS - Trying to delete certain items from a DynamoDB table

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete all records which have the attribute "code" from a DynamoDB table. Here my params:

```
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "email": "email",
    },
    ConditionExpression:"attribute_exists(code)",
};
```

This is the error:

```
{
  "message": "The conditional request failed",
  "code": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",
  "time": "2021-11-12T09:01:04.205Z",
  "requestId": "e1d74c46-86a0-4f14-8c62-186102f2aff3",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 36.80819226584606
}
```

An example record looks like this:

```
email - first_name - last_name - hash - code - confirmed
e@icloud.com - Bob - Mann - $2b$10$5/x6BkCks6ndXSr/GRhLgOPk.ettTv3lYpglbZbGnM7FXPX5VRFCe - undefined - undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html):

> ConditionalCheckFailedException
> Message: The conditional request failed.
>
> You specified a condition that was evaluated to be false. For example, you might have tried to perform a conditional update on an item, but the actual value of the attribute did not match the expected value in the condition.
>
> OK to retry? No

So the problem is with the `ConditionExpression`, the `code` attribute does not exist in some records or it exists with `undefined` value. try to change `attribute_exists` with `attribute_type`:

```
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "email": "email",
    },
    ConditionExpression:"attribute_type(code, S)",
};
```

The second parameter:

- S — String
- SS — String Set
- N — Number
- NS — Number Set
- B — Binary
- BS — Binary Set
- BOOL — Boolean
- NULL — Null
- L — List
- M — Map

read more on comparison and function on [amazondynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions).